# Macbook (late 2011) wont boot after Ubuntu install, flashing folder with question mark

Tags: boot, macbook

I am on a late 2011 MacBookPro with new/clean 1TB SSD. So no MacOS in there. 
I installed Ubuntu from a live USB.

Installation was so called successful. I did not do any partition myself, but I followed the steps suggested by Ubuntu which were:

```
partition#1 ofSCSI1 (0,0,0) (sdb) as ESP
partition#2 ofSCSI1 (0,0,0) (sdb) as ext4
```

However, now, when I start the computer, all I see is a flashing folder with a question mark on it, which apparently means no OS is found.

What can I do to overcome this?
I did found some similar questions, but they were from 2008 for dual boot. So they did not really apply to me.

**PS:** I don't have a problem booting Ubuntu as live.

Comment: Did you verify your Ubuntu install media?   If not that would be the first thing I do (just because 'live' session works doesn't mean another part of it isn't corrupt - reboot & checking your install media would be the first step I'd do if I was you).